# How to center labels and inputs with spans

Tags: html, css

I hope you all doing well!
I want to re-order fields and labels like this image [image: image of fields in a web page] :
labels have more spaces beside inputs which they also have the same width!

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.form-fieldset {
  width: max-content;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <legend>Formulaire d'inscripton :</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="inp1">Votre nom:</label>
    <input id="inp1" class="a" type="text" /><span>Le Champ est obligatoire</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <label for="inp2">Votre prénom:</label>
      <input id="inp2" class="a" type="text" /><span
        >Le prénom doivent avoir 10 caractéres en minuminat</span
      >
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="inp3">Votre Age: </label>
        <input id="inp3" class="a" type="nombre" />
        <span>Age est un nombre de deux chiffres</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="inp4"> Votre adresse email:</label>
    <input id="inp4" class="a" type="email" />
    <span>ecrire une adresse</span> mail est valide
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

This is my first post on SOF, Please Help Me?

Comment: It is not possible with the way you have set up the HTML. You'll need to use a table to recreate the kind of form from the image.  You'll need to set the minimum width of the column(use the same class name for all the corresponding cells in each row) to max-content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it. 
I put all labels `Votre nom:` `Votre prénom:` `Votre Age:` `Votre Age:` `Votre adresse email:` in one column.  All inputs in another column and all spans in another column. All columns I put inside row. `column` means `display:flex; flex-direction:column;`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.form-fieldset {
  width: max-content;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:0 5px;
}

.row {
 display:flex;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <legend>Formulaire d'inscripton :</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
          <label for="inp1">Votre nom:</label>
          <label for="inp2">Votre prénom:</label>
          <label for="inp3">Votre Age: </label>
          <label for="inp4"> Votre adresse email:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
          <input id="inp1" class="a" type="text" />
          <input id="inp2" class="a" type="text" />
          <input id="inp3" class="a" type="nombre" />
          <input id="inp4" class="a" type="email" />
      </div>

      <div class="col">
          <span>Le Champ est obligatoire</span>
          <span>Le prénom doivent avoir 10 caractéres en minuminat</span>
          <span>Age est un nombre de deux chiffres</span>
          <span>ecrire une adresse</span> mail est valide
      </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here some [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flexbox to better understand its behavior.
I've put some comment in your code (html untouched):

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.form-fieldset {
  /* width: max-content; */
  /* does not work well with 'line feed' on spans causing them to stretch beyond container, so i turned it off */
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch; /* childrens will try to fill all width of container based on its width*/
  gap: 10px; /* just for some space between element */
}
.row>*{
  flex-shrink:0; /* no shrinking, allowed proportionally by default */
}
.row label{
  flex-basis: 140px; /* set width to constant */
}
.row input{
  flex-basis: 120px; /* set width to constant */
}
.row span{
  flex-shrink: 1; /* shrink this on case of small-width container */
  flex-basis: auto; /* change in case you need to limit width*/
  flex-grow:1; /* allow grow for this elements, 0 by default */
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <legend>Formulaire d'inscripton :</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="inp1">Votre nom:</label>
    <input id="inp1" class="a" type="text" /><span>Le Champ est obligatoire</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <label for="inp2">Votre prénom:</label>
      <input id="inp2" class="a" type="text" /><span
        >Le prénom doivent avoir 10 caractéres en minuminat</span
      >
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="inp3">Votre Age: </label>
        <input id="inp3" class="a" type="nombre" />
        <span>Age est un nombre de deux chiffres</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="inp4"> Votre adresse email:</label>
    <input id="inp4" class="a" type="email" />
    <span>ecrire une adresse</span> mail est valide
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**NOTE**: Also this task can be achieved using grids on *.row* based on *display:grid* and *grid-template-columns:120px 120px auto* (plus some extra for better visuals).

**ALSO**: last *.row* have text behind span: miss-copy&paste?